# Сравнение отрицательных чисел в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, сравнение

После применения команды `cmp a, b` можно узнать, что число `a` меньше числа `b`, если `SF != OF`, но это условие не выполняется при вычитании отрицательных чисел.
Рассмотрим пример с трёхбитными числами, вычитаем `-1` из `-2`:

```
'110
-111
 ---
 111
```

Символом `'` обозначен заём, следовательно `OF` будет равен единице, но первый бит результата - `1`, следовательно `SF` тоже будет равен единице, значит, условие не выполняется. Но ведь -2 меньше, чем -1! Почему так?

Comment: Чтобы вычесть -1, нужно прибавить +1